# Как инициировать определенное действие как только переменная меняет свое значение?

Tags: c

Есть функция, которая меняет постоянно значение публичной переменной ***а***:

```
 int a;

    void foo(){
     while(1)
    {
      a = 1;
      sleep(1);
      a = 2;
      sleep(1);
      a = 3;
      sleep(1);
    }

    void bar1(){
    printf("a = 1");
    }

    void bar2(){
    printf("a = 2");
    }

    void bar3(){
    printf("a = 3");
    }
```

Необходимо выполнить 3 разные функции. Каждая из них должна выполняться сколь угодно раз, пока переменная держит свое значение ( в примере 1с). Т.е. когда значение ***а==1***, мы выполняем **bar1()** и она должна работать пока значение ***а*** не поменяется на следующее. **Как только** значение переменной меняется, **bar1()** прекращает работу и начинает работать **bar2()** и т.д.

Comment: Самый примитивный и очевидный вариант: проверять её в каком-то цикле с достаточным интервалом и вызывать подходящие функции.

Comment: @älёxölüt Проблема в том, что тут речь идет о наносекундах и моя задача сделать это как можно менее ресурсоемкой для процессора. В связи с чем, цикл проверяющий значение переменной, увы, не подходит - делал, желаемого результата не дал. Тут необходим како-то тригер, реализацию которого понять я, пока что, не могу. Спасибо.

Comment: Если переменную может поменять кто угодно, то иначе не сделать. Но если разрешать менять её через какую-то функцию, то в этой функции можно заодно и прописать, что будет вызываться на регулярной основе. Но цикл-то всё равно нужен, иначе как вы будете вызывать эти `bar`ы.

Comment: @älёxölüt Если я Вас правильно понял, то ответ:
Переменная меняется только в этой ф-ции и никто другой в нее не пишет. Переменная меняется с интервалом, который задает пользователь при инициации программы. Сам интервал тоже неопределен точно, переменная может держать свое значение секунду, менять его и удерживать 2с. 
Я думал о реализации потока на ф-цию `bar1`, а после того, как заканчивается `sleep` завершать его.  и так 3 разных потока. Но думаю, что есть что-то изящнее